# Grouping Daily data into Weekly data but incorrect grouping when year changes

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, group-by, sum

I have a basic table with daily dates and numeric value for each day. However, after the necessary filters, some dates are missing. I would like this daily data (while missing random days of the week) grouped weekly where beginning of the week would be sunday and ending of the week would be saturday. For example take the following data for one of the weeks as an example:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      DATE           |     Number       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    01/23/18         |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    01/25/18         |         5        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    01/27/18         |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    01/29/18         |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    01/31/18         |         4        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    02/02/18         |         8        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

And this is what I would like the data to show after the group:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|   Week_Start        |        SUM       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    01/21/18         |         10       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    01/28/18         |         13       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
SET DATEFIRST 7
SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, DATEPART(WEEK,a.DATE_NOTIME)-1, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, a.DATE_NOTIME), 0))   AS 'Week_Start'
      ,SUM(a.Daily_Count) AS 'Total_Weekly_Sum'
FROM
(SELECT DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t.DATE), 0) AS 'DATE_NOTIME'
       ,COUNT(t.TicketID) AS 'Daily_Count'
  FROM daily_Table t
  GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t.DATE), 0)
) AS a
GROUP BY DATEADD(WEEK, DATEPART(WEEK,a.DATE_NOTIME)-1, DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, a.DATE_NOTIME), 0))

ORDER BY DATEADD(WEEK, DATEPART(WEEK,a.DATE_NOTIME)-1, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, a.DATE_NOTIME), 0))

SET DATEFIRST 6
```

My issue with the code above is that all of year 2017 is perfectly grouped with the correct sum and dates for 'WeeK_Start' are on sundays. BUT as soon as it gets to the 2018 data, the grouping messes up and 'Week_Start' becomes Mondays. So the list looks like:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Week_Start     | Total_Weekly_Sum |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    12/17/17         |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    12/24/18         |         5        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    12/31/18         |         3        |<< Sunday
|---------------------|------------------|
|    01/01/18         |         1        |<< Monday
|---------------------|------------------|
|    01/08/18         |         4        |<< Monday
|---------------------|------------------|
|    01/15/18         |         8        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: please tag the dbms being used.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala, I have added the DBMS I am using in the tag: TSQL, SQLSERVER

Comment: I believe the problem lies with my statement:    
    SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, DATEPART(WEEK,a.DATE_NOTIME)-1, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, a.DATE_NOTIME), 0))   AS 'Week_Start'

I have tried just trying to print the dates using the above query but with manual dates from 2017 and 2018 and the result for 2018 is monday while 2017 is sunday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. It was my statement that was finding the first of week. I replaced this:

```
DATEADD(WEEK, DATEPART(WEEK,a.DATE_NOTIME)-1, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, a.DATE_NOTIME), 0))
```

WITH:

```
DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(WEEK,DATEDIFF(WEEK,0,a.DATE_NOTIME),0))
```

Now it works for any year! Hope it helps someone in need.